# Springsource Tool Suite 3.3 crashed and won't open anymore

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

My STS 3.3 crashed and I can't get it to open anymore. So far the internet has been unhelpful regarding this issue. I have tried opening with `-clean` via command prompt, but it hasn't helped. My config.ini is as follows:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

I found a log in my workspace, These are the top lines:

```
!SESSION 2016-09-09 15:58:00.722 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.3.0.201307091644-RELEASE-e43
java.version=1.7.0_79
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_SG
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide -clean

This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\Me\Documents\workspace-sts-3.3.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2016-09-09 15:58:24.424

!ENTRY oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade 4 4 2016-09-09 15:58:24.428
!MESSAGE Workspace is closed.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:399)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.upgrade.internal.J2EELibrariesRegistryUpgradeParticipant.getWorkspaceLocation(J2EELibrariesRegistryUpgradeParticipant.java:93)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.upgrade.internal.J2EELibrariesRegistryUpgradeParticipant.check(J2EELibrariesRegistryUpgradeParticipant.java:36)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.UpgradeFrameworkImpl.initialize(UpgradeFrameworkImpl.java:135)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.UpgradeFramework.initialize(UpgradeFramework.java:26)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.StartupHandler.earlyStartup(StartupHandler.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade 4 4 2016-09-09 15:58:24.431
!MESSAGE Workspace is closed.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:399)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.upgrade.internal.J2EELibrariesRegistryUpgradeParticipant.getWorkspaceLocation(J2EELibrariesRegistryUpgradeParticipant.java:93)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.upgrade.internal.J2EELibrariesRegistryUpgradeParticipant.check(J2EELibrariesRegistryUpgradeParticipant.java:36)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.UpgradeFrameworkImpl.initialize(UpgradeFrameworkImpl.java:135)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.UpgradeFramework.initialize(UpgradeFramework.java:26)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.StartupHandler.earlyStartup(StartupHandler.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-09-09 15:58:24.435
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.logging.LoggingService.log(LoggingService.java:374)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.logging.LoggingService.log(LoggingService.java:320)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.logging.LoggingService.logException(LoggingService.java:671)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.UpgradeFrameworkImpl.initialize(UpgradeFrameworkImpl.java:168)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.UpgradeFramework.initialize(UpgradeFramework.java:26)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.StartupHandler.earlyStartup(StartupHandler.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade 4 4 2016-09-09 15:58:24.440
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ResourceManager.getRuntimes(ResourceManager.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.ServerCore.getRuntimes(ServerCore.java:289)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.upgrade.internal.WlsRuntimeWorkspaceUpgradeParticipant.check(WlsRuntimeWorkspaceUpgradeParticipant.java:60)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.UpgradeFrameworkImpl.initialize(UpgradeFrameworkImpl.java:135)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.UpgradeFramework.initialize(UpgradeFramework.java:26)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.StartupHandler.earlyStartup(StartupHandler.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade 4 4 2016-09-09 15:58:24.445
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ResourceManager.getRuntimes(ResourceManager.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.ServerCore.getRuntimes(ServerCore.java:289)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.upgrade.internal.WlsRuntimeWorkspaceUpgradeParticipant.check(WlsRuntimeWorkspaceUpgradeParticipant.java:60)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.UpgradeFrameworkImpl.initialize(UpgradeFrameworkImpl.java:135)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.UpgradeFramework.initialize(UpgradeFramework.java:26)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.StartupHandler.earlyStartup(StartupHandler.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-09-09 15:58:24.450
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.logging.LoggingService.log(LoggingService.java:374)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.logging.LoggingService.log(LoggingService.java:320)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.logging.LoggingService.logException(LoggingService.java:671)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.UpgradeFrameworkImpl.initialize(UpgradeFrameworkImpl.java:168)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.UpgradeFramework.initialize(UpgradeFramework.java:26)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.StartupHandler.earlyStartup(StartupHandler.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade 4 4 2016-09-09 15:58:24.458
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ResourceManager.getRuntimes(ResourceManager.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.ServerCore.getRuntimes(ServerCore.java:289)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.upgrade.internal.WlsRuntimeNameWorkspaceUpgradeParticipant.check(WlsRuntimeNameWorkspaceUpgradeParticipant.java:52)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.UpgradeFrameworkImpl.initialize(UpgradeFrameworkImpl.java:135)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.UpgradeFramework.initialize(UpgradeFramework.java:26)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.StartupHandler.earlyStartup(StartupHandler.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade 4 4 2016-09-09 15:58:24.463
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ResourceManager.getRuntimes(ResourceManager.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.ServerCore.getRuntimes(ServerCore.java:289)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.upgrade.internal.WlsRuntimeNameWorkspaceUpgradeParticipant.check(WlsRuntimeNameWorkspaceUpgradeParticipant.java:52)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.UpgradeFrameworkImpl.initialize(UpgradeFrameworkImpl.java:135)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.UpgradeFramework.initialize(UpgradeFramework.java:26)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.StartupHandler.earlyStartup(StartupHandler.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-09-09 15:58:24.469
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.logging.LoggingService.log(LoggingService.java:374)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.logging.LoggingService.log(LoggingService.java:320)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.logging.LoggingService.logException(LoggingService.java:671)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.UpgradeFrameworkImpl.initialize(UpgradeFrameworkImpl.java:168)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.UpgradeFramework.initialize(UpgradeFramework.java:26)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade.internal.StartupHandler.earlyStartup(StartupHandler.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-09-09 15:58:24.478
!MESSAGE Bad extension specification

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-09-09 15:58:24.483
!MESSAGE Bad extension specification

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-09-09 15:58:24.488
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.ui 4 0 2016-09-09 15:58:24.493
!MESSAGE startup class must implement org.eclipse.ui.IStartup

!ENTRY oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.ui 4 0 2016-09-09 15:58:24.498
!MESSAGE startup class must implement org.eclipse.ui.IStartup

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-09-09 15:58:24.503
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:822)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2016-09-09 15:58:24.642
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Device is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.asyncExec(Display.java:709)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.ui.internal.WebtierUIStartup.earlyStartup(WebtierUIStartup.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2016-09-09 15:58:24.647
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Device is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.asyncExec(Display.java:709)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.ui.internal.WebtierUIStartup.earlyStartup(WebtierUIStartup.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-09-09 15:58:24.652
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logging(PlatformLogWriter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.log(RuntimeLog.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-09-09 15:58:24.658
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-09-09 15:58:24.662
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-09-09 15:58:24.668
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.handleException(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.ui 4 0 2016-09-09 15:58:24.674
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Device is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.asyncExec(Display.java:709)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.ui.internal.WebtierUIStartup.earlyStartup(WebtierUIStartup.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I am limited by the 30000 characters, but will be glad to post any other info required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should copy your workspace somewhere, and delete the whole directory, and then restart. If it's fixed, you should be able to reimport your projects afterwards.

Comment: eclipse based IDEs often make these kinds of problems. Do not waste your time to fix it. I recommend @fabienbk' s advice.

Comment: I would recommend to install a fresh STS, create a new workspace, and re-import the projects from their old location on disc.

Comment: Thanks all for your help! Managed to get it working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I backed up all my workspaces, then deleted them, and restarted the IDE. Had to replace everything, but at least it is working now.
Many thanks to @fabienbk for the solution.